# WPF - Button's content didn't display

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles, resourcedictionary

This is my first time to use resource dictionary to style my UI controls. Well, i have a problem to display text in button, maybe the problem is to display button i don't know what's wrong. I added resource dictionary to App.xalm. In design view it looks like all is okey - all without Text in button.

**I tried**:

- both variant with Content property and with adding text between Button's open and close tag.
- changing height and width property in style

Resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CyclingTrainingPlan">

<Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#b8c7ce" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#000" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

XALM:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" Content="Dashboard" />
```

**Solution:**

```
<Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

<!-- Properties... -->

<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1a2226"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested it here and it worked perfectly as expected.

Perhaps the problem may be in the association of this style.
Try to change from
`<Button Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" Content="Dashboard" />`
to 
`<Button Style="{DynamicResource buttonStyle}" Content="Dashboard" />`